# Will deserialized delegate work properly , in case of GC being compacted the Heap?

Tags: .net, delegates, garbage-collection

If I create a `delegate` which points to the instance method and serializes this delegate. At later point I deserialize this `delegate` and invoke. If GC runs during this time i.e. before deserializing the `delegate` will the `delegate` be able to invoke method properly? The managed object, whose instance method is pointed by delegate, may be moved to some different memory location because of memory compaction by GC. At least in my case it seems to be working but it this behavior reliable?